# Terminal: programa não instalado

Tags: ubuntu, terminal

Após eu desinstalar alguns programas sempre que eu abro o terminal aparece a seguinte mensagem

> O programa 'rbenv' não está instalado actualmente. Pode instalá-lo escrevendo:
>   sudo apt install rbenv

Como removo esta mensagem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Segundo a [documentação](https://github.com/rbenv/rbenv#uninstalling-rbenv), é necessário abrir o arquivo [`.bashrc` ou `.bash_profile`](http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/sample-bashrc.html) (depende da configuração) e remover a linha `rbenv init`, que geralmente está no fim do arquivo, e por fim, salvar as alterações.